# Search results to point to specific section?

Tags: plugins, search

Is there a way for wordpress search results to land to a specific section when using elementor or any page builders on a page or post containing the matched keyword instead of returning just the page itself? Or is there any plugin that does this?

Comment: what specific section do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include it. Something like an elementor section @Herman Nz

Comment: The same section on every result? Or the section that contains the matched text? You need to be specific about what you want.

Comment: Noted Jacob. I've updated my inquiry. Thank you!